# primus: fatal: Bumblebee daemon reported: error: Could not load GPU driver

Tags: drivers, nvidia, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee

I recently installed Ubuntu 14.04 and then installed bumblebee following the instructions on Ubuntu Bumblebee wiki(where they said that primusrun is better than optirun for version=> 13.10) But when I rebooted and tried to run primusrun with any applications (except google-chrome and firefox) the following error came(and comes):

```
primus: fatal: Bumblebee daemon reported: error: Could not load GPU driver
```

And surprisingly when I check the status of my nvidia driver, it gets on after running for example

```
primusrun clementine
sudo cat /proc/acpi/bbswitch
```

gives the following

```
0000:01:00.0 ON
```

Then, in order to avoid powerloss, I have to switch it off by bbswitch

**NOTE:** I was able to turn it off using bbswitch only after I set `Driver=nouveau` in the `/etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf` file and rebooted it.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem.

I solved changing some lines in file `/etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf`: (In my case I'm using the version 352 of nvidia driver, change this value by your driver version)

1. `KernelDriver=nvidia-current` to `KernelDriver=nvidia-352`
2. `LibraryPath=/usr/lib/nvidia-current:/usr/lib32/nvidia-current` to `LibraryPath=/usr/lib/nvidia-352:/usr/lib32/nvidia-352`
3. `XorgModulePath=/usr/lib/nvidia-current/xorg,/usr/lib/xorg/modules` to `XorgModulePath=/usr/lib/nvidia-352/xorg,/usr/lib/xorg/modules`

After that restart the system or restart the bumblebee service with:

`sudo systemctl restart bumblebeed.service`

To check the service status:

`sudo systemctl status bumblebeed.service`

and you can check the log in `/var/log/syslog` file for any error.

Regards

Answer (score 4):

new update: as I thought, changing just one line in `/etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf` actually worked out: I got everything working perfectly on updated LMDE 201403   (debian jessie based) by just adding some code to `KernelDriver` line. Before editing, it was like:

```
KernelDriver=nvidia
```

I just added `-current` to it. This is line now:

```
KernelDriver=nvidia-current
```

Now works fine with `primusrun glxgears` and `optirun glxgears`.
Haven't checked  with anything else, have no time currently. Hope this helped, cheers. :D

**EDIT:** Reason why bumblebee fails and "cannot find driver" is because of incorrect paths to nvidia driver libraries. What I do right now to make bumblebee work with any driver version I wish is changing following lines in `/etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf` file:

1. line 22: `Driver=nvidia`
2. line 55: `KernelDriver=nvidia-_version_`, i.e. `nvidia-352`
3. lines 58, 61: these lines contain paths to nvidia libraries and xorg modules. Paths probably start with `/usr/lib/nvidia`, `/usr/lib32/nvidia`, or `/usr/lib/xorg`. You should replace `nvidia` with `nvidia-_version_`, i.e. `/usr/lib/nvidia-352`. Pay attention: each line contains 2 paths, separated by colon or by comma. You should make changes to each path (DO NOT edit path that starts with `/usr/lib/xorg`).

Note that if you want to use default drivers, `_version_` should be `current`, i.e. line 52: `KernelDriver=nvidia-current`. I think that bumblebee comes preconfigured to use `nvidia-current` when package `bumblebee-nvidia` is installed (`sudo apt-get install bumblebee-nvidia`).

If done correctly, bumblebee should not report error finding drivers - this worked for me with numerous driver versions.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: This worked for me. Note that you have to "sudo systemctl restart bumblebeed" after changing the configuration files.