# Problem with nVidia drivers (how do I apply a patch)?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, bumblebee, patch

Up until my most recent `apt-get upgrade`, I was using bumblebee to manage my nvidia graphics card, and it was working perfectly - using `primusrun`, I could get upwards of 700 fps with `glxgears`. Now, however, when I try `primusrun glxgears`, I get this error:

```
primus: fatal: Bumblebee daemon reported: error: Could not load GPU driver
```

So I look in `dmesg` and see this:

```
[33359.665924] nvidia: Unknown symbol acpi_os_wait_events_complete (err 0)
```

By using `dpkg`, I see that I have these nvidia packages installed:

- bumblebee-nvidia
- nvidia-304
- nvidia-304-updates
- nvidia-current
- nvidia-settings

Googling this lead me to [this](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/644906/linux/331-20-on-3-13-rc1-kernel/) page, which suggests adding a patch to the driver and recompiling it if you have errors on kernel version 3.13 (which I'm on). Where can I find the source code for the driver to recompile it? I thought the nvidia drivers were closed source, but the people on that forum don't seem to be nvidia devs. I'm comfortable compiling packages and with `make`, but if anyone has advice compiling the driver it would be well appreciated.

Edit: I think I'm having the same problem as [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/476681/primus-fatal-bumblebee-daemon-reported-error-could-not-load-gpu-driver?rq=1) person.

Comment: You could try asking Nvidia for the source, but they would most certainly refuse to give it to you. Good luck anyway.

Comment: Then how are other people solving this? Am I missing something? There are definitely other people with this problem, who aren't nvidia devs, who have solved this.

Comment: Take a look at my answer [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-do-i-install-the-nvidia-drivers/508255#508255), see if it helps.

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't. What I ended up doing, is since I still had all my version 3.8.0 kernel packages installed, I just uninstalled the 3.13 version. So I'm using an older kernel but now everything works, for now. Hopefully the bug will be fixed soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file you need to patch is stored in `/usr/src/nvidia-??/nv-acpi.c` (in my system with `nvidia-331` the path is `/usr/src/nvidia-331-331.38/nv-acpi.c`). The driver *per se* is closed source but this file belongs to the driver/kernel interaction.

As you have both 304 and 304-updates, make sure you patch the one Bumblebee uses (in doubt patch both).

Then to rebuild kernel modules run

```
$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure nvidia-304
$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure nvidia-304-updates
```

As you can guess this is just a temporary fix. If you update any of those packages your changes go away. To avoid that [block the update of those packages](https://askubuntu.com/q/18654/33871).

Comment: Thank you! It seemed like everyone on forums, etc. knew where those files were. I suppose I should have just grepped around for them.